# http.request returning "{ type: 0 }" before actual response

Tags: angular7, ionic4

Every time I submit my Login form, the `return res;` in the `Login()` method (found below) code gets executed twice.

The first response is a simple object `{ type: 0 }`, the second is the actual response I'm looking for.

Why would `return res;` get called twice? How to I prevent that from happening?

I've stepped through the code and confirm that `login()` is only being called once, my `HttpInterceptor` is only being called once and the remote request is only being sent once.

I've upload [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBtoj.png) to help explain what's happening. You can see that only 1 remote request has been executed, but 2 responses have been logged to the console.

This problem only started a few hours ago. I've been struggling with getting ionic serve to work with CORS, I tried using `proxy.conf.json` and `proxy.js` but without having access to the API I can't allow access. For development purposes I've disable CORS in Chrome using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) because once I run the app on a mobile device it won't require CORS.

Additional toubleshooting I've tried:

1. Disabled the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * extension in Chrome and the issue persists
2. I removed the HttpInterceptor from the app.module.ts and the issue persists
3. I've tried different remote URLs (even localhost) and the issue persists
4. Shutdown Chrome and restarted PC and the issue persists
5. Tried using FireFox and the issue persists
6. I created a new Ionic4 Project and copy / pasted the same code and the issue persists
7. I tried in Chrome on a seperate machine and the issue persists

Here is my `login()` observable that is subscribed to in my `onSubmit()` method:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const body = new FormData();

  body.append('username', username);
  body.append('password', password);

  const request = new HttpRequest('POST', '[URL]', body);

  return this.http.request(request)
  .pipe(map(res => {

    return res;

  }));

}
```

Here is my `onSubmit()` and `HttpInterceptor` if it helps.

```
onSubmit () {

  this.isSubmitted = true; // I've put a break point here to make sure this method is called once

  if (!this.login.valid) {

    return;

  }

  this.authenticationService.login(this.login.value.username, this.login.value.password).subscribe((res: any) => {

  console.log(res); // this is the log that is displayed in the above screen shot

  });

}
```

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // Check auth here...

    return next.handle(request);

  }

}
```

I expect `return res;` to be called only once.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Don't use `http.request()`, use `http.post()` or similar.

Long answer:

You are using `HttpClient.request()` with an `HttpRequest` object and the [docs on `request()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) state that in this case you get an Observable over the stream of all `HttpEvent`s. The object

```
{ type: 0 }
```

is simply the first `HttpEvent` of type `Sent`, emitted directly after the request is sent but before the response arrives. The response then is the next event after that. (see [HttpEventType](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) for all possible events) To get just the response, you can simply use another method (or modify your call of `request()` according to [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request))

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed to change

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const body = new FormData();

  body.append('username', username);
  body.append('password', password);

  const request = new HttpRequest('POST', '[URL]', body);

  return this.http.request(request)
  .pipe(map(res => {

    return res;

  }));

}
```

to the following

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const body = new FormData();

  body.append('username', username);
  body.append('password', password);

  return this.http.post<any>(`[URL]`, body)
  .pipe(map(res => {
    return res;
  }));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not see any problem within the code you have mentioned but with what you have described, It seems you have set some options for your http request and the response is observing events instead of response.

```
options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]},
    observe?: 'body' | 'events' | 'response',
    params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | string[]},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
  }
```

The observe option specifies how much of the response to return.
[This link might be helpful](https://angular.io/guide/http#typed-response)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the single return statement instead of returning 2 times 
Try Using The Below Code , thanks

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const body = new FormData();

  body.append('username', username);
  body.append('password', password);

  const request = new HttpRequest('POST', '[URL]', body);

  this.http.request(request)
  .pipe(map(res => {

    return res;

  }));

}
```